# Network Indicator IOS

Tags: ios, networking, hide, show, indicator

I would like to ask that is there a way to show network indicator automatically when there is network activity going on and hide the network indicator when there is no network activity

Comment: are you using NSURLConnection methods..?

Comment: no i am using mbaas method that load stuff from the databse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to control it by using your start and completion of your network calls.

Lets say:

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      [self showNetworkActivitySpinner];
      [self fetchDataFromServer];
    }

    - (void)fetchDataFromServer{
      [SomeApiCallClass callWebServiceWithPostData:(NSDictionary *)someDataToPost andCompletionHandler:(^void) {
        [self hideNetworkActivitySpinner];
      }];
    }
```